# Multiple line tooltip with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to create a multi-line title with knockout.

With normal HTML it is not a problem (just include `&#13;`). So I tried the same with knockout, but it just shows a [simple 1 line title](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/bTDTT/) (notice a normal title when I am not using .knockout)

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;
    this.a        = ko.observable(4);
    this.b        = ko.observable(7842);

    this.tooltip = ko.computed(function() {
        return "Line1: "+self.a()+" &#13; Line2: " + self.b();
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Any idea how to make multiple line title with knockout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `attr` binding use the [`element.setAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) internally which takes a string as the attibute value.

So there is no need to XML encode the line break you can have a `\n` inside your `tooltip` string:

```
this.tooltip = ko.computed(function() {
    return "Line1: "+self.a()+"\n Line2: " + self.b();
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RQnz/).